# Quadcopter motors not spinning

Tags: quadcopter, brushless-motor

I made a quadcopter with an Arduino and all connections are fine. When I arm it, the motors spin without props but when I connect the props and arm it, the motors spin for a second and stop. Can anyone help? Why does it happen?

Comment: can you please paste a link to your arduino code (pastebin) and maybe an electronics schematic if you have one? It'd be more helpful to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Sure @morbo , i made it using the site - http://www.brokking.net/ymfc-3d_v2_qanda.html The arduino code is the same on the site.

Comment: Starting the motors with a load will definitely make the motor draw "a lot" more current. It is very likely that the motor's driver senses this surge and stops the motor for protection. You may need to slow start the motors to avoid the surge.

Comment: Alternatively, you may need to configure the max current allowed to a higher value - be careful,because it might damage your entire setup.

Comment: Are you using ESCs? If so, check using the motor and ESC specification sheet whether the battery voltage is sufficient for the ESCs and motors and also check if the ESCs amperage matches with the motors’ requirements. Remember that the ESCs’ amperage specification has to be higher than the motors’ requirements so if the motors do draw a more amps, the ESC can provide safely.